# UITableView not being populated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a method which grabs JSON and appends individual values from the JSON into the array like so:

```
internal let methods = Methods()
var countryData = [""]
@IBOutlet weak var countryTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    displayCountries()
}

func displayCountries() {

    // Wait for task to complete before grabbing JSON
    methods.getCountriesData {() -> () in

        for (_, value) in self.methods.getJSON() {
            self.countryData.append(String(describing: value))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.countryTableView.reloadData()
            print(self.countryData)
        }

    }

}
```

I have UITableView delegates declared like so also:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countryData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.countryData[row]

    return cell
}
```

The print(self.countryData) prints all of the countries within the log (100's of countries) however for some reason the countries aren't being displayed in the UITableView, does anyone understand why?

Comment: Have you specified the `dataSource` of the table view? Is the table view's frame not 0x0?

Comment: I haven't specified the dataSource. The TableView's frame is visible in the view however has no cells

Comment: Those `tableView` methods will only be called if you specify the data source of the table view. This can be done in code or in the storyboard.

Comment: How do I specify a dataSource if the data is a string Array? @nathan

Comment: I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the table view's data source. This can be done in code or in the storyboard.

**In code:**

```
countryTableView.dataSource = self
```

You will also need to have your data source object conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Since the data is an array of strings and a property on the view controller, this should work fine.

**In the storyboard:**

Simply drag the `dataSource` outlet to the object which is providing the data (in this example it is the view controller):

[image: screenshot of the data source outlet connection]

Comment: Thanks, for some reason on this line  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell it breaks as it states that it had found nil whilst unwrapping an Optional value?

Comment: Did you set the cell's identifier to "Cell" in the storyboard?

Comment: I don't have any cells at the viewLoad stage since they're added programmatically, what should be done?

Comment: I think it might be easiest if you follow this official tutorial from Apple on building a table view. It explains a lot of the concepts and has great images to follow along with: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html